# Como usar o HTTP2 no servidor Apache

Tags: apache, http, http2

Hoje no meu servidor uso o HTTP 1.1, se eu quiser atualizar para a versão 2

- O que devo fazer?
- Preciso instalar algo no servidor?
- Como a sintaxe é a mesma da versão 1.1, não influenciará a linguagem usada, certo?
- Será mantido a versão 1.1 em paralelo a 2 para ter suporte a navegadores mais antigos?

Comment: Dê uma olhada em [http2 explicado](https://http2-explained.haxx.se/content/pt/), em português. Há bastante material esclarecedor, principalmente em inglês. Ao seu propósito, https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/http2.html ;)

Answer (score 6):

**Como ativar o HTTP/2 no servidor Web Apache**

> **Para ativar o HTTP/2 no Apache, você precisará atender aos seguintes
> requisitos:**

Primeiro, você precisa ativar o  HTTPS  no seu servidor. Todos os principais navegadores permitem o uso de  HTTP/2  somente por  HTTPS. Além disso, a versão do protocolo TLS>= 1.2 com conjuntos de criptografia modernos é necessária.

Em seguida, assegure-se de estar executando o  Apache 2.4.17  ou superior, pois o  HTTP/2  é suportado a partir desta versão e para cima.

Além disso, verifique se o seu cliente/navegador realmente suporta  HTTP/2.

> **Ativar suporte a HTTP/2 no Apache**

Para que o  HTTP/2  funcione no  Apache, é necessário ativar e carregar os  módulos SSL  e  HTTP/2. Para fazer isso, você pode executar o seguinte no seu terminal:

```
sudo a2enmod ssl
```

e depois

```
sudo a2enmod http2
```

Para ativar esses novos módulos, você precisa executar:

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Após ativar e carregar os módulos necessários do Apache, navegue até o diretório de configuração do Apache e edite a configuração do Apache.

Para ativar o  HTTP/2  em seu servidor da Web Apache, inclua um dos itens a seguir em sua configuração global do Apache ou dentro de um host virtual específico.

```
Protocols h2 http/1.1
```

Aqui está a configuração mínima do servidor virtual que pode ser usada para ativar o HTTP/2 em algum host virtual:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName example.com
  ServerAlias www.example.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/public_html/example.com
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/private.pem
  SSLCertificateFile /path/to/cert.pem
  SSLProtocol all -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
  Protocols h2 http/1.1
</VirtualHost>
```

Para verificar se o seu servidor suporta HTTP/2, você pode usar suas ferramentas de desenvolvimento do navegador. Veja abaixo capturas de tela dos navegadores Google Chrome e Apple Safari que mostram HTTP/2 em ação no  domínio https://example.com .

Para testar se o HTTP/2 está funcionando Acesse este site `https://tools.keycdn.com/http2-test` digite o domínio desejado.

**Veja abaixo o ex:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> **Como a sintaxe é a mesma da versão 1.1, não influenciará a linguagem
> usada, certo?**

**Sim pois:**

- Estas são as diferenças de alto nível entre o HTTP1 e o HTTP2:
- HTTP2 é binário, em vez de textual
- O HTTP2 é totalmente multiplexado, em vez de ordenado e bloqueado
- HTTP2 pode, portanto, usar uma conexão para paralelismo
- HTP2 usa compactação de cabeçalho para reduzir a sobrecarga
- O HTTP2 permite que os servidores “empurrem” as respostas proativamente para os caches do cliente

O HTTP/2 não modifica a semântica HTTP do aplicativo de nenhuma forma. Todos os conceitos-chave, como métodos HTTP, códigos de status, URIs e campos de cabeçalho, continuam da mesma forma. Na verdade, o HTTP/2 modifica como os dados são formatados (em frames) e transportados entre o cliente e o servidor, os quais gerenciam todo o processo, e esconde toda a complexidade dos aplicativos dentro da nova camada de frame. Assim, todos os aplicativos existentes podem ser fornecidos sem modificação...

No HTTP 2.0 e no SPDY, há uma solução melhor, chamada de server-push. A ideia é que o servidor pode mandar alguns recursos para o navegador sem ele mesmo ter requisitado ainda. Imagine o browser requisitar o index.html e o servidor já responder o index.html, o style.css, alguns ícones etc. O servidor empurra para o navegador recursos que ele sabe que seriam requisitados logo em seguida. Com isso, quando o navegador precisar do recurso, já vai ter em cache e não será preciso fazer um request.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Será mantido a versão 1.1 em paralelo a 2 para ter suporte a
> navegadores mais antigos?

Sim, porem com o tempo é natural que vá se migrando para o HTTP/2

Referencia:

> https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-enable-http-2-in-apache/
>
> https://www.greenlanemarketing.com/blog/seo-101-http-vs-http2/
>
> https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/http2/?hl=pt-br
>
> https://blog.caelum.com.br/as-fantasticas-novidades-do-http-2-0-e-do-spdy/